# Allocation large memory in visual studio C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio C in window to write a function to allocate large memory. If I test it with small value(small than 3000x6000-3000 is number of rows and 6000 is number of columns), it will be correct. However, when I test with large value about (30000,60000), It will error with message "Unhandled exception at 0x0f6bc9d0 in LargeMemory.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000." -0x0f6bc9d0 is address of 2D point. How to resolve this problem. This is my code

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include <memory.h>
    int** memoryAllocation()
    {
          int nRow=30000;
          int nColumn=60000; 
          int **ppnGMatrix=NULL;
          ppnGMatrix =(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*nRow);
          if(ppnGMatrix!=NULL)
          {
            for (int nRowIndex = 0; nRowIndex < nRow; nRowIndex++)
            {
                ppnGMatrix[nRowIndex] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nColumn);
                memset(ppnGMatrix[nRowIndex], 0, sizeof(int) * nColumn);
            }
          }
          return ppnGMatrix;
    }
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        int** GMatrixAllocate=NULL;
        GMatrixAllocate=memoryAllocation();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should check the returns of malloc for 0 ( NULL ).

Comment: @CharlieBurns: I edited it, but it cannot resolve this problem. Problem is how to allocate large memory in my code?

Comment: Yes Sir, My memory is 8Gb and run window 64 bit.

Comment: Physical memory should not matter (too much) but you may not have enough virtual memory (address space), or it may not be all in a large enough block.

Comment: "Access violation writing location 0x00000000" pretty much says one of your mallocs is returning 0 and your are writing in memset anyway.

Comment: As tietnes says below Make sure you are compiling as a 64 bit executable. I'm not a windows person so I can't tell you have to do that. But if you are building with 32 bit pointers, your code will fail. tletnes say 1.8G, my calcs say 6G.

Comment: Yes sir. I changed it to 64 bit and run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to allocate 1.8*4GB of memory.

**First:** Make sure you are compiling as a 64 bit executable, 1.8*4GB will use more memory space than is available in 32bit. Even if you have that much space free in your address space it may not be contiguous (all in one block) which is what malloc will look for.

**Second:** redesign your code, any time you get to a point where you need contiguous blocks of such a huge size it probably means you need to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Thank you. I think my combiner is 32 bit. I changed it to 64 bit and run successfully. Other way, Do you have idea to allocate large memory?

Comment: We did the 1.8G number come from? You have 30000 * 60000 * sizeof(int) plus all the row pointers ( 30000 * sizeof(int *))

Comment: In fact it is 1.8G of elements. Given an int32 (4 bytes per element), it means 7.2GB. Not to mention all the additional pointers to the `rows`. +1 anyway.

Comment: Yep @SJuan76 figured it out, I forgot to multiply by 4.

Comment: @user2408476 this is how to allocate large memory. I think you need to consider what problem you are trying to solve and see if there is another way to solve it.